# RoR: Set PaperClip Image model :path for S3 bucket correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

In my Rails 4 app, I am storing my images on S3 using PaperClip. Any of my image in S3 bucket looks like this:

https://mybucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/images/files/000/001/920/original/40a6885fc09c8ed4e1e3745d7f7fb770.jpg

Now in order to serve images through **AWS CloudFront CDN**, I am following [this article](http://www.entreprehero.com/serve-assets-cdn-s3-cloudfront-rails4-paperclip/) suggesting to set `:path` attribute in my Image model. What will be exact value for it here ?

```
has_attached_file :file, styles: { small: '120x50', medium: '350x350' }, :path => "images/files/../../:id/:style/:filename"
```

Specifically, I am not sure about how to handle the **/000/001/** part in image URL above. Because these are arbitrary folders which PaperClip has created while saving images on S3. Otherwise, `:id, :style and :filename` is correctly replacing their values at runtime.

Comment: This is indeed strange, as S3 evidently doesn't place restrictions on the number of assets in a bucket at the present.

Answer (score 0):

When using the file system **there are limitations as to the amount of files that can be stored in each folder**.

On a Linux system if you were to store more than 32,000 files in a folder you would receive an error.  **For this reason paperclip automatically partitions your files into separate folders**, that is what it is doing by the 000/001/920 in your above example..... this is necessary.

It is taking the object id which is 1920 and prepending it with 0's to get nine digits, then splitting them into separate partitions.  If you must manually set the path, instead of letting paperclip handle this logic, you must also manually partition your files otherwise you will eventually run into big problems.

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation. But my problem is that the images are already stored on S3. Now in order to use a CDN, I have to provide **:path** as template so that PaperClip may substitute CDN host value instead of direct bucket path for every image.

Comment: But the only _question_ you stated above was "I am not sure about how to handle the /000/001/ part in image URL above".  the /000/0001/ part of the file path above is part of the associated object id, the full formatted id would be 000001920.  What would be returned from you automatically by :id would be 1920.  You need to use regex's to identify if it is a number less than 9 digit's and if so prepend it with 0's to format it to 9 digit's than perform a split operation and add backslashes for directory breaks /.  If :id was 555444666 you would need to format to /555/444/666

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to do anything about :path, you need to make sure config.action_controller.asset_host points at your CloudFront domain name, not to the S3

Answer (score 0):

The symbol you're looking for is :id_partition.

So whole path would be

`images/files/:id_partition/:style/:filename`